# Access Tableview Cell in some other methods

Tags: iphone

How to access a table view cell in some other user defined methods other than those predefined methods for tableview???

Plz help...
Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 0):

for that you have to take the cell as global variable and acess it anywhere.

But remember untill you call the tableview reload method no change is gonna reflect.

So I suggest better use the cell in predefined delegate methods rather than trying to experiment (which can cause problem in consistency).

Happy Coding...

Comment: I solved the problem...using the code below...
NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPlay inSection:0]; 
[tv selectRowAtIndexPath:index animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];


here tv is my tableview and indexPlay is a global int variable keeping track of indexpath.row

I just wanted to change the highlighted state of the cell selected or deselected...

Comment: then you must be specific in your question.

You question was 
How to access a table view cell in some other user defined methods

instead it must be
How to change the behaviour of cell selection. or as per your comment
I just want to change the highlighted state of the cell selected or deselected...

Any of the above question will be fine. You have asked something and expected something else. I am not wrong on my way. I have answered as per the question. Still got down vote :(